# Prove that $Tr((AB^2)A)=Tr(A^2B^2)$

Tags: matrices, trace

> Prove that for every $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$: $$Tr((AB^2)A)=Tr(A^2B^2)$$

I need a solution that doesn't use expansion. One more question comes into my mind: given $A,B$ are square matrices. For which condition of $A,B$ we can conclude that $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No condition, this holds [for all matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Trace_of_a_product).

Comment: Why not use expansion? I think that's the best way to prove it within elementary linear algebra.

Comment: @Arashium: That's not true.

Comment: If expansion means writing down the trace in terms of the explicit entries of $A$ and $B$, that's a terrible way of solving the problem. The relation $\operatorname{tr}(XY) = \operatorname{tr}(YX)$ holds for arbitrary $X, Y$ (square of the same dimension), and that's enough to prove the statement in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for $A,B\in M_{n\times n}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}\trace(AB)
&= \sum_{k=1}^n [AB]_{kk} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n[A]_{kj}[B]_{jk} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n [B]_{jk}[A]_{kj} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n [BA]_{jj} \\
&= \trace(BA)
\end{align*}

Comment: @Arashium true. This answer is brilliant but I think the OP wants some novel one without expansion :P

Comment: @Arashium absolutely not. Merely that the trace of $AB$ is the same as the trace of $BA$.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. How silly I can forget such a property!

Answer (score 1):

$${\rm Tr}(AB^2A) = {\rm Tr} \big((AB^2) A \big) = {\rm Tr} \big(A (AB^2) \big) = {\rm Tr}(A^2B^2)$$

using the property ${\rm Tr}(XY) = {\rm Tr}(YX)$.